# Loss from linear transformed output and ground truth for training

Tags: pytorch, transformation, backpropagation, loss

I have a prediction model in pytorch that takes inputs and generates outputs in a specific coordinate system. In my process I transform the output and ground truth into a different coordinate system (2-dimensional translation and rotation). I can now calculate the loss in both coordinate systems, which have the same values (RMSE and NLL loss).

Does it matter which loss I use for the training to run loss.backward() on?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

> Does it matter which loss I use for the training to run loss.backward() on?

No for MSE, Yes for NLL.

Assuming that ground truth vector is `x` and the output vector is `y`,

Old MSE = `(x-y).T.dot(x-y)`

After the transformation, ground truth vector becomes `A.dot(x)` and output becomes `A.dot(y)`.

New MSE = `(x-y).T.dot(M).dot(x-y)` where `M=A.T.dot(A)` where `A` is the transformation matrix.

Due to properties of linear transformation, we also have `A.T.dot(A)=I`

So, we can see that `M` will always turn out to be identity matrix and hence the MSE remains unchanged.

Now, NLL loss which is typically applied after `nn.LogSoftmax` just does
`Y[x].mean()` where Y is the output after `nn.LogSoftmax` and x is the target.
(I am referring to [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html)).

This is not the same as what you'd get after you linearly transform output and target.